# How to calculate the Green function of 1D Kitaev chain?

Tags: condensed-matter, fourier-transform, greens-functions, second-quantization

After performing Jordan-Wigner transformation, a uniform transverse Ising model becomes a 1D Kitaev chain as

$\hat{H}_{p=0,1} = -J\sum_{j=1}^{L}{(\hat{c}_{j}^{\dagger}\hat{c}_{j+1}+\hat{c}_{j}^{\dagger}\hat{c}_{j+1}^{\dagger}+h.c.)} + h\sum_{j=1}^{L}{(2\hat{n}_j-1)}$

with

$\hat{c}^{L+1} = (-1)^{p+1}\hat{c}_1$

for different $p$ sector.
Assume $J,h>0$.
Since we focus on the ground state of the system, so we only have to consider the $p=0$ sector.
Next step is performing a Fourier transformation with choice for $k$ as

$\{k=\pm2(n-1)\pi/L, n =1,\dots,L/2\}$,

after that the original Hamiltonian can be block-diagonolized into some 2*2 $\hat{H}_k$.

Then we focus on how to calculate the correlation function $<\hat{c}_{m}^{\dagger}\hat{c}_{n}>$ of 1D Kitaev chain.

My calculation gives the result that

$<\hat{c}_{m}^{\dagger}\hat{c}_{n}> = 2\sum_{k>0}{\cos(k(m-n))<\hat{n}_k>}$

Here comes the problem.
For example, we consider $L=4$ case. With the formula above, $<\hat{c}_{1}^{\dagger}\hat{c}_{3}> = 2\sum_{k>0}{\cos(2k)<\hat{n}_k>}$.
One can easily find that $\cos(2k)=\cos(2k)=0$ for all $k$s however generally $<\hat{c}_{1}^{\dagger}\hat{c}_{3}> \neq 0$.
Actually I find that the result of Green function is correct for $|m-n|=0,1$ but incorrect for other cases.

My question is that where is the mistake during my calculation?